# SOAP Request Over PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I tried to create a request for SOAP wsdl, the request & response of the request is:

**SOAP request:**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:sub="http://subscriberprovisioning.ws.nvsmx.domain.com/">
<soap:Header/><soap:Body>
<sub:wsGetSubscriberProfileByID><subscriberID>123456789</subscriberID><alternateID></alternateID><parameter1></parameter1><parameter2></parameter2>
</sub:wsGetSubscriberProfileByID></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

**Response**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap:Body><ns2:wsGetSubscriberProfileByIDResponse xmlns:ns2="http://subscriberprovisioning.ws.nvsmx.domain.com/">
<return><responseCode>200</responseCode><responseMessage>SUCCESS</responseMessage><subscriberProfile>
<entry><key>SUBSCRIBER_IDENTITY</key><value>123456789</value></entry>
</subscriberProfile></return></ns2:wsGetSubscriberProfileByIDResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I am using php to create the request the code look like this:

**request.php**

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient("http://ipnumber:1988/services/Subscriber?wsdl"); 





$param = array('subscriberId' => '123456789');
$response = $client->wsGetSubscriberProfileByID    ($param);

var_dump($response);
```

within above code the the `'subscriberId' => '123456789'` doesn't pass to the wsdl and I got the missing parameter response. I tested also using SOAP UI, and it working. Any suggestion for my php code.

Thanks

Comment: You code lines seem to be doubled and in the wrong order. Start by removing the doubles, and put the lines in the right order.

Comment: Hi @KIKOSoftware, thanks for the response, can you please in more details?

Comment: You only need 1 `SoapClient`, not 2. The first `$soapclient->wsGetSubscriberProfileByID()` doesn't seem to be used, and has an undefined argument. These are quite obvious flaws in the code. If you do not see these then creating a SOAP request might be too big a challenge for you.

Comment: Hi @KIKOSoftware, i already try to only using one SoapClient `$client` before asking here and anly called `$client->wsGetSubscriberProfileByID()`

I edited my code in question, within code without double soapclient

Comment: Well, that looks better. Is there any documentation for this SOAP request? Clearly you're missing a parameter, the documentation could tell you what they should be.

Comment: I am not sure, but I will asking for. But when I tried using the SOAPUI it's working well, what I think is, the `$param = array('subscriberId' => '123456789');` this doesn't pass to wsdl.

Thanks @KIKOSoftware

Comment: In other words: What's running on your local host, port 1988?

Comment: Not localhost actually, that's the ip for the SOAP server.

Comment: Ah, that was confusing. Yes, 'ipnumber' is better than '127.0.0.1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it got working within this code:

```
try{
$soapclient = new SoapClient('http://ipnumber:1988//services/Subscriber?wsdl');
$param=array('subscriberID'=>'123456789');
$response =$soapclient->wsGetSubscriberProfileByID($param);
var_dump($response);
echo '<br><br><br>';
$array = json_decode(json_encode($response), true);
print_r($array);
 echo '<br><br><br>';
      echo '<br><br><br>';
    foreach($array as $item) {
        echo '<pre>'; var_dump($item);
    }  
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```